# What is the fastest method to count elements of a tensorflow.data.Datset?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Is there a faster way to count all elements of a `tensorflow.data.Dataset` than

```
def count_elements(dataset: tf.data.Dataset):
    return dataset.reduce(0, lambda x, _ : x + 1).numpy()
```

"Faster" means also taking into account memory usage, but execution time is paramount. As far as I can see there is no built-in method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer "No".

For in-memory datasets there's: `tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset)`, but `tf.data.Dataset`s are inherently lazy loaded, and can be infinite, so there's no knowing how many elements there are in a `tf.data.Dataset` without iterating through it.

Credit: [In TensorFlow 2.0, how can I see the number of elements in a dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369900/in-tensorflow-2-0-how-can-i-see-the-number-of-elements-in-a-dataset)